# How Do I Filter the Custom Labels List Based on the Installed Package Name?

Tags: list-view, customlabel

Trying to filter the Custom Labels list by finding all the labels from the Salesforce CPQ package. Figured I'd do this by using Create New View with the criteria `Installed Package | contains | CPQ` for the Field | Operator | Value fields. Problem is this is not filtering correctly and shows a blank list. Any thoughts on why this is? Can the View not filter based on the Installed Package name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBQQ is the namespace of Salesforce CPQ.

So, you can create the filter with either conditions: `Installed Package equals "SBQQ"` OR `Namespace Prefix equals "SBQQ"`.

Comment: So it searches based on the Namespace Prefix rather than the Package Name for that, huh? Good to know. Thanks mate!